# Detecting runTime process is finished

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg to export the video.
I run the exe file from my java code.

```
val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("$ffmpeg .....)
while (process.isAlive) {
   //waiting
}

if(process.exitValue() != 0) {
//failed
}
else {
//successful
}
```

If any errors occur in FFmpeg, process will return an exitValue not 0 to tell me there is something wrong.
But when the file or dir includes forbidden characters, it will be a " No such file or directory" error in ffmpeg, however it doesn't return anything to the java program, so the program sticks at process.isAlive part.
Is there a better way to detect the process is finished or not?

Comment: why don't you check the existence of the file itself ?

Comment: It always generates a file(whether can be opened or not)

Comment: I'm not sure what are you talking about

Comment: @Ravi Sorry, I misunderstood your question, import files are existing, but if the file names include forbidden characters, it will be a " No such file or directory" error in ffmpeg.

Comment: You should have included such scenarios in your question to make your question clear and make specific.

Comment: Thanks, I added it to my question.

Comment: Can you add example of forbidden file name ?

Comment: I'm not sure the rule, in my case "&" is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can get better control of the Process by using ProcessBuilder and Process classes directly instead of Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Also, unless it's a typo, you want `process.isAlive()` instead of `process.isAlive`
(it's a method call, returning a boolean).

Comment: If I use Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), there is not a proper workaround? Thanks for reminding me, the code is written in Kotlin, so ( ) is omitted.